# ANT attribute in regex pattern

Tags: java, regex, ant

I'm writing an utility macro which involves checking whether a comma-separated list `list` contains or does not a particular value `value`.

```
<macrodef name="csvcontains">
    <attribute name="value"/>
    <attribute name="list"/>
    <attribute name="casesensitive" default="false"/>
    <sequential>
    <condition property="matched" else="false">
        <matches string="@{list}" pattern="TODO" casesensitive="@{casesensitive}"/>
    </condition>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

I cannot get the pattern right, because I'm not sure of how to escape `@{value}` (and to match a comma-separated pattern).

How to build the pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried? It is my understanding that ant resolves all variables in a first step, so you probably don't have to escape `@{value}`

Comment: I was getting errors but I discovered they're not related to escaping:  `pattern="(^|,{\s})@{value}({\s},|{\s}$)"` . This is the pattern i'm trying but i get errors near position 3

Comment: It's the curly brackets around `\s` - you can say `,{4}` to match 4 commas but repeating a comma "`\s`-times" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I opened a new question for the regex itself. ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030340/ant-element-in-csv-matching))

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that @ and { mean something in regular expressions.  You can work around that by building your regex into a property, then pass the new property to your pattern attribute.  He's an example:

```
<property name="versioning.official.build"
          value="The Daily Build"
          />
<property name="dollar.signs.mean.something.in.regexes"
          value="^${versioning.official.build}_\d"
          />
<condition property="versioning.checkin">
    <matches string="${versioning.build.name}"
             pattern="${dollar.signs.mean.something.in.regexes}"
             />
</condition>
```