# ANT element in csv matching

Tags: java, regex, ant

I need to write a regex to match an element in a comma-separated list, ignoring whitespaces near `,`.
For example:
`elem1, elem2  ,elem3,  elem4  ,elem5 ,elem6`

Any of: `elem1` `elem2` `elem3` `elem4` `elem5` `elem6` should match.

The trailing comma (before end of line) is not allowed.

I tried this pattern:
`pattern="(^|/,)\s*@{value}\s*(/,|$)"`
but it doesn't work. (False negative)

How can i do that pattern? What's wrong in mine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution:

**The pattern is**:

```
^(.+,\s*|\s*)@{value}(\s*|\s*,.+)$
```

*An usage example is*:

```
<macrodef name="csvcontains">
    <attribute name="value"/>
    <attribute name="list"/>
    <attribute name="propertyName"/>
    <attribute name="casesensitive" default="false"/>
    <sequential>
        <condition property="@{propertyName}" else="false">
            <or>
                <isset property="@{propertyName}"/>
                <matches string="@{list}" pattern="^(.+,\s*|\s*)@{value}(\s*|\s*,.+)$" casesensitive="@{casesensitive}"/>
            </or>
        </condition>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Comment: I don't know ant. The xml won't interpolate between dbl quotes, so `\\s` wasn't necessary. But your rx will allow ' ,value, ' . Why didn't `(^|,)\s*@{value}\s*(,|$)` or `(^|,)\s*@{value}\s*(?=,|$)` work?

Answer (score 1):

Interpolation is your problem. And, you can't consume the ',' on both sides, you can only consume it on one side.

**Edit** - That is if you are searching in a global sense, then you can't consume a comma on both sides. For instance if you want to find ALL of something. If its just find the first match only then a comma on both sides is OK. I don't know about java but, you can't just plop a list into a regex and expect it to match unless its set up as an alternation first. Like `"(?:^|,)\\s*(?:elem4|elem6)\\s*(?=,|\$)"`. For sure you need another escape on the whitespace `\\s`.

```
$value = '(elem.)';  
$rx    = "(?:^|,)\\s*$value\\s*(?=,|\$)";
```

or

```
$rx    = '(?:^|,)\s*(elem.)\s*(?=,|$)';
```

In Perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $value = '(elem.)';

my $str = ' elem1, elem2 ,elem3, elem4 ,elem5 ,elem6 ';

my $rx = "(?:^|,)\\s*$value\\s*(?=,|\$)";

while ( $str =~ /$rx/g ) {
   print "'$1'\n";
}
```

Output

`'elem1'`
`'elem2'`
`'elem3'`
`'elem4'`
`'elem5'`
`'elem6'`

Answer (score 0):

From your previous question, you want to test, if a csv list *contains* a special value. This is a different task - and a different ant task too:

```
<macrodef name="csvcontains">
    <attribute name="value"/>
    <attribute name="list"/>
    <attribute name="casesensitive" default="false"/>
    <sequential>
    <condition property="matched" else="false">
        <contains string="@{list}" substring="@{value}" casesensitive="@{casesensitive}"/>
    </condition>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

(You may think about renaming the property `matched` to `contained`)

Comment: The problem is that if I pass as element `python` and in the list there is `pythonic` and not `python` that condition matches, and I don't want that. I need only exact element matching.